# Django pet_picture.board_id may not be NULL

Tags: django

***The problem is when a user submit a picture I get this error.
I think I understand why I get this error because the board dropbox is not validating even though I select a Board.***

```
IntegrityError at /picture/
pet_picture.board_id may not be NULLRequest Method: POST 
Request URL:  
Django Version: 1.4.3 
Exception Type: IntegrityError 
Exception Value: pet_picture.board_id may not be NULL 


Traceback:

File "C:\o\mysite\pet\views.py" in PictureCreator
  106.          picture = Picture.objects.create(user=request.user)
```

***I think The problem is at my PictureCreator function at  views.py***

```
 def PictureCreator(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pet.views.LoginRequest'))

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PictureForm(request.POST , request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            picture = Picture.objects.create(user=request.user)
            picture.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            picture.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            picture.board = form.cleaned_data['board']
            picture.save()
    return render(request,'picture.html',{'form':PictureForm()})
```

***I think the problem At this particular statement It does not valid my board dropbox . How can I make it valid?***
                picture.board = form.cleaned_data['board']

My parts of my forms.py

```
class PictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    board = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Board.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ('image','description','board',)
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name



class Picture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

How can I fix this? Thank you for helping me :D

Comment: did you try to put null value in board?

Comment: @catherine Should I put a null value?

Comment: No, I'm just asking :)

Comment: @catherine I think this is the problem cause I created one similar to this but no dropbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is on this line:

`picture = Picture.objects.create(user=request.user)`

Based on your model, a `Board` is required when creating a `Picture`. One way to resolve this is to change the aforementioned line to:

`picture = Picture(user=request.user)`

Now you have to call `save` explicitly which you are doing below in your view already.

Answer (score 2):

```
picture = Picture(user=request.user)
picture.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
picture.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
picture.board = form.cleaned_data['board']
picture.save()
```

Comment: it's ok as long as it's answer your question